# How to replace the name of a country or it's ISO code with a flag emoji

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I saw a Data Studio dashboard that had the emoji flag of each country instead of its name. How can I get the emojis when I'm building a Data Studio dashboard using data in BigQuery?

[image]

(from https://datastudio.google.com/s/p_EyXtEOKek)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the emoji flag of each country, you could join with my public table `fh-bigquery.util.country_emoji_flags`. For example:

```
WITH countries AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['cl','us','in','jp']) country
)


SELECT *
  , (SELECT emoji FROM `fh-bigquery.util.country_emoji_flags` WHERE country=iso_lower) emoji
  , (SELECT name FROM `fh-bigquery.util.country_emoji_flags` WHERE country=iso_lower) country_name
FROM countries
```

[image]

If you want to re-build the table, find the .tsv at:

- https://github.com/fhoffa/code_snippets/blob/master/util/emoji_flags.tsv

Comment: . . I realize that questions are not supposed to ask about off-site resources.  However, this is one of the more interesting things I've seen here recently.